# applying complex function to more datasets in r

Tags: r, lapply

I have a function that looks like this:

```
filter <- function(x,lambda){
eg <- diag(length(x))
result <- solve(eg+lambda%*%crossprod(diff(eye,lag=1,d=2)),x)
return(result)
}
```

I want to apply it to more datasets but lapply does not work:

```
re <-lapply(my_data, filter(x,6.5))
```

Why?

Comment: What kind of object is `my_data` ? Could you post the result of `dput(my_data)` (or maybe  `dput(head(my_data))` if too big)?

Comment: `re <- lapply(my_data, filter, lambda=6.5)` read the documentation of `lapply()`: FUN= is a function-object (not calling a function)

Comment: `my_data` is a list of vectors that i want to apply this function to. every vector has 100 rows.

Comment: if i use `re <- lapply(my_data, filter, lambda=6.5)` than i get  `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (lambda = 6.5)`

Comment: Rename your function. `filter` is a function in the stats package and there is also a `filter` function in the dplyr package. Those might be used in your call (but I don't really know for lack of a reproducible example, which you really should supply).

Comment: @Roland I have vectors like this `data_1`: ` V1`
`1   92.2`
`2   77.4`
`3   59.5`
`4   57.2`
`5   66.8`
`6   74.3`
`7   84.9`
`8   93.0`
`9   80.4`
`10  93.4`
`11 102.9`
`12 129.0`
`13 146.0`
`14 773.1`
`15 223.3`
`16 228.2`
`17 127.8`
`18 249.9`
`19 274.8`
`20 872.8`
`21 300.2`
`22 357.3`
`23 367.7`
`24 342.7` and i made a list of them: `my_data = paste0("data_", 1:100)` and i want to apply function filter to them, before i named it something else so it is not about the name.

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question body (click "edit"). Also, `my_data` is a character vector and not a list.

Comment: for me this works fine: `L <- list(BOD, BOD);
f <- function(x, a) x$demand+a;
lapply(L, f, a=15)` please edit your question and include the data!

Answer (score 1):

```
re <-lapply(my_data, function(x) filter(x,6.5))
```